# Space between overlapping nodes?

Tags: tikz-arrows

I am currently working on a simple `tikz` state machine image, in which I have some problems creating some space within the path connecting A - B and  B - A.

Since they are on the same line, both lines also occur on the same line, which makes it hard to see that they are two separate lines.

How do I separate them?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm,
                    semithick]
  \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=red,draw=none,text=white]

  \node[initial,state] (A)              {State i};
  \node[state]         (B) [right of=A] {State j};

  \path (A) edge       node {$P_{ij}$} (B)
        (B) edge              node {$P_{ji}$} (A)
        (A) edge [loop above] node {$P_{ii}$} (A)             
        (B) edge [loop above] node {$P_{jj}$} (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do

```
\path (A) edge [bend left]  node {$P_{ij}$} (B)
      (B) edge [bend left]  node {$P_{ji}$} (A)
      (A) edge [loop above] node {$P_{ii}$} (A)             
      (B) edge [loop above] node {$P_{jj}$} (B);
```

to obtain:

[image]